# auto center programmatically created UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2

How can I make sure that my views ( UIButton in this case ) are always centered in the middle no matter how many I have? ( see image for example )

[image]

I am making them programmatically from within a loop. But this way it only works when there is 4 buttons.

```
var i = 220

for button in optionButtons {
    button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i), 280, 150, 150)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: "pressedOption:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    })
    CGFloat(i += 150)
}
```

But this only works when there are 4 of them. How do I make this work with less then 4?

Comment: Why not just a UIStackView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically create autolayout format string and add constraints to the view.

```
let button1 = UIButton()
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button1.setTitle("button 1", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let button2 = UIButton()
button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button2.setTitle("button 2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let button3 = UIButton()
button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button3.setTitle("button 3", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let buttons = [button1, button2, button3]
let spaceBeetweenButtons = NSNumber(int: 10)
let buttonWidth = NSNumber(int: 80)
let buttonHeight = NSNumber(int: 35)

let containerWidth = NSNumber(integer: (buttons.count * buttonWidth.integerValue) + (buttons.count - 1) * spaceBeetweenButtons.integerValue)
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

var views = [String : AnyObject]()
let metrics = ["buttonWidth" : buttonWidth, "buttonHeight" : buttonHeight, "spaceBeetweenButtons" : spaceBeetweenButtons, "containerWidth" : containerWidth]
var format = "H:|-0-"

for var i = 0; i < buttons.count; i++
{
    views["button\(i)"] = buttons[i]
    format += "[button\(i)(==buttonWidth)]"
    if i != buttons.count - 1
    {
        format += "-spaceBeetweenButtons-"
    }
    else
    {
        format += "-0-|"
    }
    containerView.addSubview(buttons[i])
    containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[button\(i)(==buttonHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeftToRight, metrics: metrics, views: views))
}

containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeftToRight, metrics: metrics, views: views))

self.view.addSubview(containerView)
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[containerView(==buttonHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeftToRight, metrics: metrics, views: ["containerView" : containerView]))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[containerView(==containerWidth)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeftToRight, metrics: metrics, views: ["containerView" : containerView]))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! this is exactly what I was searching for. One thing I miss, How do I center the "container" in the center of the screen vertically?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

Build a superView that containing all your buttons Like this.
[image]

Next, you only need to center the superView.

### *Update: How to auto get the size of superView?*

At first, it's easy to set the position of the superView.

Then, if your button's size and the space between them are fixed. The superView's width and height can be decided by the childViews.

[image]

Feel free to ask me. Thanks!

Comment: But How Do I (auto)expand that view to show all the buttons?

Comment: Programmatically add auto layout constraint -> 1st button begin position to last button end position is width of your container view.